# Need to loop a formula increasing until last column

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I looked around but can't find quite exactly a function that does what I need. I am basically doing a find a replace but only on cells with an X and replacing with the value of it's own header

```
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Replace What:="X", Replacement:="=B2", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Replace What:="X", Replacement:="=C2", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Replace What:="X", Replacement:="=D2", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

This continues all the way until whatever the last column is. In this case it is CD. This is incredibly impractical obviously and a way to loop this, where the value for Replacement:="=B2" would just go up by a column value on each pass would be ideal.

Comment: Why are you looking at **xlPart**? Should the X be the only thing in the cell?

Comment: Yes, it is a giant grid of blank cells with only an X where there is a "hit".  This grid is roughly 12.6 million cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that row 2 is one that you should base the extent upon seeing as that is what gets transferred in the [Range.Replace method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx).

```
Sub X_to_HDR()
    Dim c As Long
    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        With .Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1).Offset(1, 1)
                For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    With .Columns(c)
                        .Replace What:="X", Replacement:=Chr(61) & .Parent.Cells(2, c + 1).Address(0, 0), _
                                 LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False
                    End With
                Next c
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I've changed your *xlPart* to *xlWhole*; change this back if you feel the original was more appropriate.

Comment: This works perfectly.  You just saved me couple hours of work. I owe you a beer

Answer (score 1):

Here's a loop that should get you what you need based on your description:

```
Sub LoopColumns()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'chnage as needed

Dim rColumns As Range, rCell As Range
Set rColumns = ws1.Range(ws1.Range("B2"), ws1.Range("B2").End(xlToRight)) ' asssumes contiguous range of headers

For Each rCell In rColumns

    rCell.EntireColumn.Replace What:="X", Replacement:=rCell.Value2, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: "Invalid or unqualified reference" for 
.Range

Comment: @Antibios - you must have copied the code b4 my edits. glad you got your answer, either way.